# Calling Foo::Bar from Bar::BazController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model namespaced under `Company`

```
class Company::Employee
```

I have a controller for the profiles of my employees, namespaced under `Employee`

```
class Employee::ProfilesController < EmployeeController
```

I set `@employee` in that controller

```
@employee = Company::Employee.find(...)
```

But I have the error

> undefined method `find' for Employee:Module

It seems that `Company::Employee` is resolved to the `Employee` module that hosts `Employee::ProfilesController`.

When I byebug there, I have an extra message `warning: toplevel constant Employee referenced by Company::Employee`. How could a controller module be referenced by a model class?

I tried some stuff including `::Company::Employee` and `require 'company/employee'`, but nothing changes.

The files in question are in

- `app/controllers/employee/profiles_controller.rb`
- `app/models/company/employee.rb`

Trace

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `find' for Employee:Module):

app/controllers/employee/profiles_controller.rb:30:in `set_company_employee'
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (7.0ms)
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.5ms)
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.
0ms)
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescue
s/layout (2726.3ms)
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (
1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5
ms)
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (2507.8ms)
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)
  Rendered C:/dev/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (4939.1ms)
```

classes

```
class Employee::ProfilesController < EmployeeController
  before_action :set_company_employee
  ...

  def set_company_employee
    if params[:employee_id]
      # Line that throws error below :
      @employee = (Company::Employee).find(params[:employee_id])
    else
      # Many employee profiles, bad request
      flashy_now(:error, :select_employee_profiles)
      redirect_back
    end
    @company = @employee.company
  end

class Company::Employee < Professional
  include Invitable

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :entity

  delegate :name, to: :company, prefix: true
  delegate :name, to: :entity, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

end

class Professional
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include SimpleEnum::Mongoid
  include Likeable
  include UserProfile
  ...
  belongs_to :user
  ...
```

Config

- ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x64-mingw32]
- Rails 5.0.0beta3

Comment: Show your full classes and the full error messages with line numbers.

Comment: Here you go. My custom modules most likely have nothing to do with the problem, they just add a few fields and delegation stuff with ActiveSupport::Concern

Comment: What a joke, if I execute a line before that requires the good class through an other association, like `Company.first.employees.first.class`, it actually solves the problem. However It stops working as soon as I remove this line. If anyone can explain that...

Comment: Does exploding out the module definitions change anything? (e.g. `module Company; class Employee`)

Comment: @JoshBodah I thought it did at the beginning, but then I realized I somehow had non-deterministic behavior, it would work well the first time and fail on consecutive calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [this nice article](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/) which explains how autoloading can be a mess.

I'm still not sure why this error happens in my particular case, but some of the comments pointed out that `require_dependency` could help me and it did :

After adding those 2 lines on top of my `Company::Employee` controller, everything seems to be working fine

(Note that I also really needed to add the second one or I'd get a `NoMethodError (undefined method 'where' for Company:Class):`

```
# app/controllers/company/profiles_controller.rb
require_dependency "company/employee.rb"
require_dependency "company.rb"
```